# Use Superagent with A+ spec?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, superagent

How can I use [Superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) but with the Promises A+ spec?  I'm working on a project that uses both Superagent and [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) and I would like to use the `.then()` syntax but can't figure out an easy way to do this without writing my own wrapper code.

[I see this project](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/superagent-bluebird-promise)   but don't want to  have to use the .promise() on each call.

Are there any other existing modules which make it look more like Bluebird?

Something more like -

```
var request = ('superagent-wrapperModule');

request.get(url).then(..).catch(...)
```

[EDIT] I've actually made a module to do this the way I'd prefer (similar to above example).

If anyone's interested - [github link](https://github.com/jxm262/blueagent) and [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blueagent)

Comment: Without the using the `.promise()` at the end of each call how would the library know when you actually wanted to send the request?

Comment: The thing is that `superagent` doesn't send the request until you call `end`, so even if you do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/victorkohl/caeb46566183dbe6715f), using `promisifyAll`, you'll have to call `endAsync` to send the request.

Comment: @idbehold , I'm thinking you would need to actually create and return a new Promise explicitly (assuming using Bluebird here), and manually call call the resolve/rejects.  I'll see if I can get a gist to explain it better.  The other option is to probably rewrite Superagent to be Promise based.

Comment: @victorkohl Ok, [here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/jxm262/b150fa87840f56fd8284) I made which demonstrates your idea, but adding the `.then( )` to the prototype chain.  Seems to work perfectly, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JustinMaat Looks interesting, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @idbehold and @victorkohl commented, `superagent` requires a call to `end` to know that the request is being sent. To do so, the `superagent-bluebird-promise` adapter have chosen to use a `.promise()` method, which also takes an option object.

If you don't like that and don't need options, I would recommend that you simply define your own `then` method on the request objects:

```
var request = require('superagent-bluebird-promise');
request.Request.prototype.then = function(s, e) {
    return this.promise().then(s, e);
};
```

so that you can use

```
request.get(url).then(…).catch(…);
```

<sub>(I've also opened [a Github issue](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/superagent-bluebird-promise/issues/15) on this)</sub>

Comment: I like your method name much more than `.promise()`

Comment: Well, it's not just "a method name" but the A+ interoperability feature :-)

Comment: It might be a better idea to only add the `then()` method to the object after calling one of the get, post, put, patch, or delete methods on the superagent object.

Comment: @idbehold: I have no idea how superagent works, don't all these functions on the exported object return `Request` instances? If `request` already is one, then what happens if you call `.end()` directly on it?

Comment: @Bergi , I'll mark this as accepted.  I'm adding the link to our ticket/discussion from github in case anyone else is interested.  https://github.com/KyleAMathews/superagent-bluebird-promise/issues/15